# in awk facing issues while using variable as search pattern while searching in a file

Tags: bash, file, shell, design-patterns, awk

```
date;
tocompdate=$(date --date="-90 days ago" +%d%m%Y)
echo $tocompdate;

awk -v pattern="$testdate" '{print "Some matter "nr[NR--]" matter "$testdate""};' tocompare.txt >> mail2sent.txt`
```

Here I am taking current date and adding 90 days to it and storing it in `tocompdate`. And comparing `tocompdate` with a file, where same date is present in a line and some other matter in other line before that line.

while search pattern is matched I need some text to be printed and "the line before matched line" to be printed and again matched line after few words.

For example:

File has below content

```
a1
28112019
b2
04032018
c3
04032018
d4
27072015
e5
27072015
f6
06012030
```

If I am comparing with `27072015`, I want output as below

```
The d4 is on 27072015
The e5 is on 27072015
```

Comment: What is the question here exactly? How to use `pattern` as the pattern to match against?

Comment: yes ...matching the pattern in file and printing oneline before match string with matched string

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk -v tgt="27072015" '$0==tgt{printf "The %s is on %s\n", p, $0} {p=$0}' file
The d4 is on 27072015
The e5 is on 27072015
```

Comment: Thanks. The guys who invented shell for manipulating files and processes and sequencing calls to tools, also invented awk as the tool for shell to call to manipulate text files so it's just horses for courses... If you'll be doing any text manipulation in UNIX, I strongly recommend the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Answer (score 0):

I propose a solution using only shell programming:

```
#!/bin/sh 

match="27072015"

while IFS= read -r i
do if [ "$i" = "$match" ]
   then printf "The %s is on %s\n" "$last" "$match"
   fi
   # test that we are not in a whitespace
   if [ -n "$i" ]
   then last="$i"
   fi
done < tocompare.txt
```

Note: This solution is only appropriate for very small and simple data sets without special characters. Additionally it's much slower than using `awk`.

Comment: Depending on the contents of `compare.txt` that would corrupt it on output. It'd also be immensely slow for a large file. Using shell loops is always the wrong approach, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice. And don't use all-upper case for non-exported variable names by convention and to avoid clashes with builtin names like HOME, PATH, IFS, etc.

Comment: IIf the file contained `a\tb` then `while read i` would populate `i` with `atb` because `read` strips escapes by default. It also has unexpected effects with spaces. Any time you write a shell loop to read lines from a file unaltered you need to write `while IFS= read -r i` unless you have a specific task in mind and fully understand all the caveats of not doing so. Why does shell behave that way? Because, like with unquoted variables, shell is not intended for manipulating text so it's default behaviors make sense in some shell-appropriate contexts but NOT for manipulating text.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun: Another solution using `sed`, `grep` and `xargs`

```
xargs -n 2 <file | grep -E '\b27072015$' | sed -r 's/^(\S+)\s(\S+)$/The \1 is on \2/g'
```

you get,

```
The d4 is on 27072015
The e5 is on 27072015
```